# Spring Authorization Server - how do you implement a 'log' out user functionality?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I've been trying to log out a user by accessing the `token/revoke` endpoint from the authorization server, but I only get a 404.

At the moment, I can't even find the endpoint for revoking the token and I don't know what to do. How do you figure out what's the actual endpoint for revoking the token?

The only other topic I can find on the matter is this one:

[Spring oauth2 authorization server: unable to logout users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70735327/spring-oauth2-authorization-server-unable-to-logout-users) but after implementing this answer, I still get a 404.

Here's what I have:

```
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(withDefaults());
        http.logout()
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        return http.build();
    }
```

How do I even begin revoking the token of an authenticated user?

Answer (score 3):

The token revocation endpoint on Spring Authorization Server is `/oauth2/revoke`, and it implements [RFC 7009](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7009) (OAuth 2.0 Token Revocation Endpoint). You can always call `/.well-known/openid-configuration` or `/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server` to discover these values, which also allows clients to "self-configure" based on the provider.

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70777564/15835039), logout is not connected to token revocation by default, because OAuth 2.1 is focused on authorization, not authentication. You would have to connect them through a customization, which is touched on in that answer. The situation may be improved in the future as we work through implementing additional pieces of the OpenID Connect 1.0 family of specifications.

However, if you're using Spring Security with the backend-for-frontend pattern (BFF) on the client and also using OpenID Connect to log in, you can configure logout. See [OpenID Connect 1.0 Logout](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-oidc-logout) in the reference docs for more information.

Comment: After attempting to implement the oidc `LogoutSuccessHandler`, the post redirect URI seems to fail as it cannot retrieve an `end_session_endpoint` provider endpoint uri despite the `OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler` recognizing that I have a valid `OidcUser`. I am not sure what exactly am I doing wrong, can you give me any pointers?

Comment: Also, I think you made a mistake in your op, I think the default revocation endpoint is `/oauth2/revoke`, as stated in the source code.

Comment: Ah, thanks for catching that. I think the logout success handler may need to be customized. See [#543](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/543) as it is related. Since I haven't built a sample yet, I don't have any pointers but hopefully we can put one together soon. Feel free to up-vote that issue so it gets priority.