# Spring Security OAuth2 Authorization Server

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, spring-authorization-server

I'm currently using Spring Security OAuth2 Authorization Server in order to generate jwt's for user that connect to my app. Problem is that Spring Security OAuth2 Authorization Server by default has the following workflow:

1. Access authorization endpoint to fetch a auth code . You will be prompted to enter your credentials (username and password ). Then you will be saved in the security context
2. Access token endpoint to fetch the token. In this moment the spring auth server knows how to throw you a jwt because it sees the security context from the previous point.

The problem is that this doesn't work for multiple users , meaning that if another user comes and do a request, it will not prompt him again to enter credentials , it will see the previous user in the spring security context. How do you overcome this scenario? Wasn't Spring Authorization Server built for such scenarios?

UPDATE:

Handling multiple users is not a issue here, they will all be stored in the spring security context by their session, it was a misunderstanding on my side.

Comment: I feel that there's some missing information from this question, as hinted in the comments of an answer below. Are you using client authentication method of `none`? Also, please describe your expectation regarding multiple users. Are you expecting the entire flow to be stateless? Note that most authz servers create a user session, which is what you're seeing. How do you intend to "switch users" as your comment indicates you need to do?

Comment: I've added an answer below based on some of your comments. If I'm on track, It might still be helpful to update the question for clarity.

Comment: I replied to your general answer below so we might continue the discussions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Token revocation requires client authentication, and therefore is not possible by default when using a public client. The OpenID Connect 1.0 Logout Endpoint [was recently added](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/pull/1068), which is designed specifically for this case and requires an ID token instead of an access token. This feature will be released in version `1.1`.

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71650060/15835039) for an explanation of why token revocation and logout are different (though please note that the above logout functionality has been added since this answer was written).

Comment: Hello Steve and thanks a lot for your time! What is an ID token and how will i obtain it in order to logout? I edited my question so now it should be more clear to you.Forget about the multiple users thing, i was confused but now i get the picture :d

Comment: @loredon it seems you've completely changed the question. Please ask a new question. If my answer answered your original question, please mark it as accepted or if not, the edited question should clarify things instead of add new questions.

Comment: I updated the question accordingly and kept its original context. I have created another question about other unclear aspects : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75755586/spring-oauth-authorization-server-logout

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a scenario when one user "steals" a valid token generated by the previous user and is able to make subsequent calls.

To mitigate this - or at least to reduce the impact - every token has a limited TTL (time-to-live) and expires after that time.

Calling API with an expired (invalid) token invoke the login page.

Comment: You test that on same browser ? Security endpoint (IdP) have a session so you will be not prompted to connect with another user. You need to logout of IdP to change user.

Comment: Ok, i tested with a icognito window and confirm that it works now. I also debugged a little and i see that on the request headers there is a JSESSIONID ( which basically is a cookie ) so i don't understand why its on the headers rather than on the request cookies. But now remains the question, how can i make so that i can trigger again the user credentials check for myself, maybe i wanna switch a user?

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque i have found out that i can logout a user if i overwrite the response handler for revoke endpoint, thus, revoking a token and also logging out the user but despite the fact that the client authentication is set to none, revokation endpoint requires me to authenticate and i don't know why cause i don t have no client secret.

Comment: Just find documentation about Single Logout : SLO.

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque well that's why i asked in the comments, i cannot find a suitable documentation for implementing Single Logout in Spring Authorization Server and also i cannot find how to disable the authentication for the revocation endpoint.